# Why my action creators is not defined in react redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have made component Notification and I want its action and reducer to be available to all the app.
But I am not getting why my action is saying not defined.
Here is the code

```
import { SHOW_NOTIFICATION, SHOW_NOTIFICATION_FULFILLED } from 'constants/actionTypes'

// notification
const initialState = {
  notification: {}
}

export function fetchNotification (data) {
  return {
    type: 'SHOW_NOTIFICATION',
    data: data
  }
}

export default function notificationReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_NOTIFICATION_FULFILLED: {
      return {
        ...state,
        notification: action.data
      }
    }
  }
  return state
}
```

`SHOW_FULFILLED` is showing defined but never used so whats the mistake

Comment: i think you are importing them incorrectly, here : `'constants/actionTypes'` it should be either start with `./constants/` or `../constants/`

Comment: No I am importing it in right way

Answer (score 0):

You call action with `SHOW_NOTIFICATION` but reducer handle only `SHOW_NOTIFICATION_FULFILLED`. Use same action type in reducer as in action.

```
// notification
const initialState = {
  notification: {}
}

export function fetchNotification (data) {
  return {
    type: 'SHOW_NOTIFICATION', // <--
    data: data
  }
}

export default function notificationReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_NOTIFICATION: { // <--
      return {
        ...state,
        notification: action.data
      }
    }
  }
  return state
}
```

Comment: No I am using promise middleware which handles this way